# «Обошла восемь врачей» или «Обошла восьмерых врачей»?

Tags: числительные

«Обошла восемь врачей» или «Обошла восьмерых врачей»?

Answer (score 2):

Вне особенного контекста, объединяющего врачей в **группу**, "восьмерку" (обошла восьмерых врачей, дружно устроивших перекур, и зашла в палату), правилен вариант "*обошла (посетила) **восемь врачей***".

Comment: Да, обозначение ситуации важно, трудно сказать без контекста, что имеется в виду в приведенном предложении. Еще пример в тему (о диспансеризации сотрудников фирмы): Вчера пришлось обойти восьмерых врачей! Здесь важно эмоционально подчеркнуть их количество.  Язык дает такую возможность, отчего бы ей не воспользоваться?

Comment: В лучшем случае возникает вопрос: а что, в этой поликлинике ровно восемь врачей?

Comment: А там бумажечку дают с указанием отведенного вам количества, чтобы вы совсем не потеряли здоровье к концу осмотра.

Comment: А вот это уже _внешний_ контекст, проясняющий основания для выражения с "восьмерыми". Без него возникает недоразумение.

Comment: Alex_ander, а здесь окружающие в курсе этого внешнего контекста, поэтому понимают вас.

Comment: Выражение предложено _вне_ контекста, Можно только гадать, стояли они кучкой, подразумевались как все существующие или в предписании их было ровно восемь. Выражение же "обошла восемь врачей" имеет законченный смысл и не вызывает вопроса, что именно хотели сказать.

Comment: Смысл законченный, но к конкретной ситуации не привязаннй, а в разговорной речи это важно. У вас получается "законченный смысл" сам по себе, как абсолютная ценность, а в реальности значимость ситуации всегда присутствует. Это всего лишь пример, но речь идет о том, что не стоит считать одно всегда правильным, а другое всегда неправильным. Я, собственно говоря, именно это имею в виду.

Answer (score 1):

Собирательные имена числительные обозначают количество предметов как одно целое, как совокупность, а в Вашем примере имеется в виду не совокупность, а "посетила каждого из 8 врачей по очереди", следовательно употребление собирательного числительного некорректно.

Корректно: *«Обошла восемь врачей»*.

Comment: А если такая фраза: "Илья Муромец победил всех троих (или восьмерых) братьев Змея Горыныча"?

Comment: "**Всех** троих (восьмерых)" - корректно на основании того, что дополнительно обозначена конечная группа "все три". В нашем случае для понимания "восьмерых" требуется вступление вроде "мне было предписано посетить _восемь_ разных врачей", после чего возможно "я обошла всех восьмерых".

Comment: Согласен! Если, скажем, добавить "А потом он одолел восьмерых братьев Кощея Бессмертного" - здесь нужно "восьмерых" - потому что контекст предполагает, что их всего было восемь, то есть конкретная группа. А если братьев было всего сто, а он одолел восемь из этих ста, то нужно использовать "восемь".